# Cannot install xplayer from X-Apps PPA

Tags: apt, ppa, gstreamer

I cannot install xplayer from the X-Apps PPA on Ubuntu 17.10

Package manager says that it depends on gstreamer1.0-clutter but that gstreamer1.0-clutter cannot be installed. I do have gstreamer1.0-clutter-3.0 installed but it seems this is not recognised as being related.

I don't have any problems with totem on Ubuntu 17.10. The most recent Ubuntu release on which I have successfully installed xplayer is Ubuntu 16.04.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be packaging issue. A can confirm it on my clean installation of Artful.

Below is not recommended, but you can download dependendent package [from Xenial](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&exact=1&searchon=names&keywords=gstreamer1.0-clutter) manually and then install xplayer:

```
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/c/clutter-gst-2.0/gstreamer1.0-clutter_2.0.18-1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i gstreamer1.0-clutter_2.0.18-1_amd64.deb

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:embrosyn/xapps
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install xplayer
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks, worked first time. I notice that the command line example in your answer assumes I'm using amd64 architecture, which I didn't actually specify - but no worries, I think you've explained how to get the dependent package sufficiently well for me to be able to figure out how to do it for any architecture.